# Can I pass a list query within this constant?

Tags: reactjs, amazon-dynamodb, aws-amplify

Well I have the following code and I was wondering is it possible for me to pass the results of a `listquery` e.g `listRestaurants` within `const suggestions`. so that it returns the results of the `listquery` and also returns the 2 labels "Pizzaday & Pizzario"?`If yes how would one go about doing this. Thanks!

````
const suggestions = [

  { label: 'Pizzaday' },
  { label: 'Pizzario' },

];```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So imagine you have

```
const listRestaurants = ['Resto1', 'Resto2'];
```

and then you have:

```
const suggestions = [

  { label: 'Pizzaday' },
  { label: 'Pizzario' },

];
```

If what you want is:

```
const suggestions = [
  'Resto1',
  'Resto2',
  { label: 'Pizzaday' },
  { label: 'Pizzario' },
];
```

You can do it like this:

```
const suggestions = [
  ...listRestaurants,
  { label: 'Pizzaday' },
  { label: 'Pizzario' }
]
```

For more information check : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Array_destructuring

Comment: awesome thanks but I had to add label to the 2 Restos in listRestaurants

Comment: If you want to programmatically add them you could do like `...listRestaurants.map(restaurant => ({ label: restaurant }))`